# Android RecyclerView CardView StaggedGridLayoutManager: Independent column scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have "regular" implementation of [`StaggedGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html). Is it possible to achieve independent column scroll? For example the user will touch and scroll the right column, so other columns will not move?

And even further: When scrolling the right column other columns will also scroll synchronously but in slower rate? (This is similar to what was in Expedia App once).

Thanks,

Comment: like a fruit machine. should be possible, but scrolling the other columns smoothly, not 100% sure that possible because you scroll by position not pixels although you may be able to offset by postion. for that you need to forgo recycleview and use scrollView instead. eg. create 2/3 scrollviews next to each other put the card items in there and use this tutorial to scroll the views by pixels -- http://android-er.blogspot.com.cy/2011/09/scroll-view-scrollby-and-scrollto.html

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you aren't just doing multiple recyclers with your data spread across them?  You could use an OnScrollListener or custom implementation to get the parallax you described.

Comment: Ben: May I ask you why did you posted this comment as 'Answer'? The content is actually classical comment not a solution. And to the point the suggestion is the 'Trivial solution' for this issue - something that well known especially to all 8 people who voted it up and probably interested in the solution. So this question listed in the unanswered list and therefore the exposure is high. After your answer/comment it's not and therefore the chances to get answer is low - As far as I can understand this is not the way SO community should behave.

Comment: I posted as an answer because you cannot have columns in a staggered list view move independently.  You would have to tie three custom scrollers to one recycler which means you would essentially be writing your own list view from the ViewGroup up, which would not use the RecylerView as was requested.